# How to see certificate contents for incoming request in Django?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am building an Endpoint to receive data inside POST request, And a webserver is going to send that request to my server, and they have SSL Certificate, Now i need to verify inside my API View that the request is coming from them not anyone else, And i will check that by getting their Digital Certificate and check it, Now how can i view their certificate inside the request in Django View?

Comment: Not very clear. Is is the work of webserver to checking SSL certificate, not Django ? What webserver are you using ?

Comment: @LucasGrugru There is a website will send a POST to my API, And they asked me to check the certificate for the incoming request that they made to check it's really coming from them not anyone else, So i want to see certificate details to verify it's them and let my API continue it's work